# Preparation of categorical data for hierarchical clustering

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, data-processing, categorical-data

I would like to use R to perform a hierarchical clustering of data that looks like this:

```
     L1   L2   L3
W1   p    pr   r
W2   p    NA   r
```

which is supposed to mean that L2 shares feature W1 with both L1 and L3, while feature W2 is present in L1 and L3, but with a different value, and missing from L2. (*edit* L’s are languages, W’s are stems of words in these languages, and the values (p, r, etc.) describe how these words can be derived in the specific language. I believe that a word’s being derived in the same way in different languages might suggest common origin. When it's missing, it's not clear: it might mean something, or my sources might be incomplete, but I guess I'll have to cautiously assume the first option. The eventual goal is to classify languages by what stems are present in them, and how they behave. *end edit*)

Can you please explain how I can transform this data so as to be able to perform classification on them, and advise on what similarity index I should use?

Comment: Can you please be clearer about which are the objects to be clustered?

Comment: @Michele I've edited the post and briefly explained what my data represent. Please let me know if a more detailed explanation is needed.

Comment: In the first instance, could you use the same value for all three, or does `pr` mean that L2 has two values for this feature? In the latter case, an enumeration like `feature(L1,W1,p); feature(L2,W1,p); feature(L2,W1,r); feature(L3,W1,r)` might make more sense than a single matrix over W and L.

Comment: @tripleee It means that L2 has two values. Where can I find out more about how to code such an enumeration in R? I don't seem to be able to find it with Google.

Comment: Just change the layout of your table, maybe rows of W and values indicating (language,feature) tuples for that W? Or using language as the primary key might make more sense from a usability point of view.